# Is there any Swift API that tells whether fast user switching is enabled or not in macOS?

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode, macos

Is there any swift API that tells whether fast user switching is enabled or not?

We want to do something when fast user switching is enabled and something not when it's not enabled. Looking for an API that tells whether it's enabled or not

Comment: It might be stored in a user preference. Try using PlistWatch to find it https://developer.okta.com/blog/2021/07/19/discover-macos-settings-with-plistwatch